# Mysql Select from table where a date is max for each unique location_id AND product

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table - records - that looks like this

```
id | location_id | product | stock | date  
===|=============|=========|=======|======
1  | Bakery 1    |  cake   |  21   | 2
2  | Bakery 1    |  bread  |  23   | 2
3  | Bakery 2    |  cake   |  21   | 2
4  | Bakery 2    |  bread  |  21   | 2
5  | Bakery 1    |  cake   |  21   | 3
6  | Bakery 1    |  bread  |  23   | 3
7  | Bakery 2    |  cake   |  21   | 3
8  | Bakery 2    |  bread  |  21   | 3
9  | Bakery 1    |  cake   |  21   | 4
10 | Bakery 1    |  bread  |  23   | 4
11 | Bakery 2    |  bread  |  23   | 4
```

For each location and for each product, i want to pick the row that has the highest date value. Which will look like ths

```
id | location_id | product | stock | date  
===|=============|=========|=======|======
7  | Bakery 2    |  cake   |  21   | 3
9  | Bakery 1    |  cake   |  21   | 4
10 | Bakery 1    |  bread  |  23   | 4
11 | Bakery 2    |  bread  |  23   | 4
```

How do i execute this with one query? I could loop through all the locations and all the products and build the queries but its more time and memory consuming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select r1.*
from records r1
join
(
  select location_id, product, max(date) as date
  from records
  group by location_id, product
) r2 on r1.location_id = r2.location_id 
    and r1.product = r2.product
    and r1.date = r2.date
```

Comment: This is the only way, since MySQL doesn't have aggregate functions. On Oracle you could just do ```select location_id, MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY location_id)``` *sigh*

Comment: @amenadiel This *isn't* the only way, but it *is* a good way!

Answer (score 1):

If the following conditions are true you can do this job very efficiently using the `id` column

1. your `id` column is autoincrementing
2. the `date` column represents the current date: that is, you never insert a backdated record.
3. you don't UPDATE the `date` column

If these conditions are true, that means the unique identifier `id` can be used as a proxy for the non-unique value `date` for each record.  A row with a higher `date` value is always guaranteed to have a higher `id` value.

If you can do this you can make your query perform very well.

First, you create a subquery to get the `id` of the latest row for each combination of location and product.

```
SELECT MAX(id)
  FROM records
 GROUP BY location_id, date
```

Then you use that set of `id` values to pull the correct records from your table

```
SELECT *
  FROM records
 WHERE id IN (
                SELECT MAX(id)
                 FROM records
                GROUP BY location_id, date
              )
ORDER BY location_id, product
```